# Light weight add on not installing on client machine

Tags: sapb1

I have deployed a light weight add-on through extension manager for SAP 9.2, in the server the add-on is installed and works as expected. But in client machine, the add-on is not getting installed.

I tried all of these,

- Un-assign and re-assign the add-on to the company 
  Check the SAP
- Client agent is running
- Remove the AddOnsLocalRegistration.sbo and    AddOnsInstall.sbo files
- Check company/server
- Set add-on as mandatory

We have 2 add-on's that uses ARD instead of extensions to register and these add-on's are installing correctly without any issues.

I have even tried to copy the add-on folder and the AddOnsLocalRegistration.sbo from server to local and surprisingly found that SAP is uninstalling the addon when i log in. Users are using SSO to sign in to SAP B1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in SAP. Note: [2467361](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2467361)

**Symptom**
In your SAP Business One application, you have enabled single sign-on and you have assigned several lightweight add-ons using the Extension Manager. After you bind a SAP Business One user with a Microsoft Windows account, the lightweight add-ons disappear from the Add-On Manager.

**Cause**
Application error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the AddOns folder has full rights for everyone to read/write.

Change this under `Properties->Security->Edit`

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One\AddOns